# Iterate through all my Reddit comments with PRAW?

Tags: python, praw

I'm trying to fetch all comments and then delete them.

```
import praw

r = praw.Reddit(...)

print("\nFetching all comments ...")
i = len(list(r.user.me().comments.new(limit=None)))
print("Found " + str(i) + " comments. Processing ...")

comments = r.user.me().comments.new(limit=None)
for c in comments:
    c.edit(body="deleted").delete()
    print("  - Comment " + c.id + " deleted, " + str(i - 1) + " to go")
    i = i - 1

print("\nAll done!")
```

The (shortened) output looks like this.

```
Found 268 comments. Processing ...
- Comment ie8hwqq deleted, 267 to go
...
- Comment i9txf1j deleted, 168 to go

All done!
```

The odd thing is that it stops after processing 100 comments. You can see that converting the iterable to a list and checking the length does show it contains 268 comments. But when looping through iterable, it only iterates through the comments 268 to 169 and then exits the loop.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I assume `comments` is some smart object. Can you materialise it into a list before iterating? `comments = list(comments)` (seeing as it's quite small)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. I suspect that is has to do with changes to rate limits of the Reddit API that PRAW hasn't accommodated. I used a workaround with a method that will repeatedly process comments in batches of 100:

```
def process_comments(comments):
    i = 0
    for comment in comments:
        i += 1
        comment.edit(body="deleted").delete()
    return i == 0
```

Then elsewhere:

```
import praw

r = praw.Reddit(...)

processing = True
while processing:
    comments = r.comments.new()
    processing = process_comments(comments)
```

If `process_comments` returns `True`, it means that:

1. there are more comments to process; or
2. there was exactly 100 comments in the batch.

Either way `process_comments` will break out of the loop once it has processed <100 comments in a batch, which will be 0 in the subsequent call in case 2).